# In Python, how to make data members visible to subclasses if not known when initializing an object?

Tags: python

The title is a bit long, but it should be pretty straightforward for someone well-aware of python.

I'm a python newbie. So, maybe i'm doing things in the wrong way.

Suppose I have a class TreeNode

```
class TreeNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        Node.__init__(self, name, id) 
        self.children = []
```

and a subclass with a weight:

```
class WeightedNode(TreeNode):
    def __init__(self,name, id):
        TreeNode.__init__(self, name, id)
        self.weight = 0
```

So far, i think I'm ok. Now, I want to add an object variable called father in TreeNode so that WeightedNode has also this member. The problem is that I don't know when initializing the object who is going to be the father. I set the father afterwards with this method in TreeNode :

```
def set_father(self, father_node):
    self.father = father_node
```

The problem is then when i'm trying to access self.father in Weighted:

```
print 'Name %s Father %s '%(self.name, self.father.name)
```

I obtain:

```
AttributeError: WeightedNode instance has no attribute 'father'
```

I thought that I could make `father` visible by doing something in `TreeNode.__init__` but i wasn't able to find what.

How can i do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just initialize it with a default value:

```
self.father = None
```

That way the attribute will at least be recognized. And this is valid since at this point there really is no `father`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've already done that and I obtained:
`   print ' Name %s Father %s '%(self.name, self.father.name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
`

Comment: crap, that's because that was not initialized when i reached this point of the program. right ?

Comment: Correct, you need to make sure father isn't None before you can use name.

Comment: Asking stupid questions isn't stupid though; at least you're learning - we've all been there (at least) once ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In response to your statement on Justin's answer, try this:

```
print ' Name %s Father %s '%(str(self.name), str(self.father.name))
```

The str() command will get a string representation of an object even if it's `None`

Comment: Why would that help?  It's simply that at the time the print statement is run, self.father is still None...

Comment: It would stop the application crashing. I agree that it doesn't solve the underlying problem though.